# How to validate checkbox group with Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a group of checkboxes in my Vue + Vuetify project. I want to validate that at least one checkbox is checked using Vuetify's ["Validation with submit & clear"](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#validation-with-submit-clear).

Validating a radio group is easy and it works fine by applying a rule to the radio-group:

```
<v-radio-group v-model="radio" required :rules="radioRules" row>
    <v-radio label="A" value="a"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="B" value="b"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="C" value="c"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, for checkboxes I can not find a group option like `v-checkbox-group`, so my checkboxes look like this:

```
<v-checkbox class="pr-6" v-model="selected" label="A" value="a"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox class="pr-6" v-model="selected" label="B" value="b"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox class="pr-6" v-model="selected" label="C" value="c"></v-checkbox>
```

**Question:**

How can i apply a rule to the checkboxes that validates that at least one checkbox is checked, `this.selected.length > 0` ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `rules="required"` would work here.

Comment: This would require all checkboxes to be selected, i want only at least one checkbox to be required to be selected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done with an array as `v-model`. Just use computed property for validation:

```
computed: {
    rules() {
      return [
        this.selected.length > 0 || "At least one item should be selected"
      ];
    }
  }
```

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ysemeniuk/pen/gOYGaVZ)

Also pay attention how `hide-details` property of `v-checkbox` is used.

Comment: That works very nice. in case your list is dynamic, you'll need to use index in the v-for, then use it in hide-details, to hide everywhere but the last one, like this:
:hide-details="index != options.length - 1"

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you define your `selected` field of your model an array, and bind it the checkboxes like below?

```html
<v-checkbox class="pr-6" v-model="selected[0]" label="A" value="a"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox class="pr-6" v-model="selected[1]" label="B" value="b"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox class="pr-6" v-model="selected[2]" label="C" value="c"></v-checkbox>
```

For validation:

```
return this.selected.filter(s => s === true).length > 0
```